# Not pretty-printing a field of a record

Tags: coq

Suppose I have such record type:

```
Record myRec : Type := {
  myNat : nat;
  myProof : myNat > 0
}.
```

How can I tell Coq to parse but not pretty-print (i.e., hide) the field `myProof` of a value of type `myRec`?

Can it be set while declaring the record type?

Or should it be done using the `Notation` command and the `only printing` syntax modifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it is indeed with notations.

```
Record myRec : Type := myRecBuild {
  myNat : nat ;
  myProof : myNat > 0
}.

Notation "⟪ x ⟫" := (myRecBuild x _).
```

Now if you have a value of `myRec` it will only print the relevant part.

```
Lemma foo :
  forall (x y : myRec),
    x.(myNat) = y.(myNat) ->
    x = x.
Proof.
  intros [x hx] [y hy] e.
  simpl in e. (* replaces myNat ⟪ x ⟫ with x *)
  (* Goal is now ⟪ x ⟫ = ⟪ x ⟫, hiding hx and hy *)
Abort.
```

I would argue that you don't need the `only printing` option. In fact, this can be handy if you want to easily provide the relevant part and leave the rest to automation / tactics.

```
Lemma bar :
  exists (x : myRec), x.(myNat) = 1.
Proof.
  unshelve eexists ⟪ 1 ⟫.
  - auto.
  - reflexivity.
Qed.
```

This can become particularly handy when using `Program` or `Equations`.

Comment: But, with your approach, if I have other record types with fields to hide, I will need to introduce a different notation for each record type. I would like to use the built-in notation `{| myNat := 1 |}`.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way it could be done. In any case, you would to specify it for each record as there is now way Coq will guess which arguments you want to see.